# Remove default page name from URL for all subfolders

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, friendly-url

I'm using Microsoft's [ASP.NET Friendly URLs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj891077(v=vs.111).aspx) to do some simple URL cleanup.

The site I'm working on has quite a few subfolders, each with its own `Default.aspx`. I'd like to remove the `Default.aspx` portion of the URL any time it appears.

Examples:

```
//Original: www.mysite.com/Default.aspx
//Goal:     www.mysite.com/

//Original: www.mysite.com/Users/Default.aspx
//Goal:     www.mysite.com/Users/
```

---

The library removes the extension by default, and I'm able to (roughly) accomplish my goal by doing the following:

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Root Default", "", "~/Default.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Subfolder1 Default", "Subfolder1/", "~/Subfolder1/Default.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Subfolder2 Default", "Subfolder2/", "~/Subfolder2/Default.aspx");
...
...
...
routes.MapPageRoute("Subfolder24 Default", "Subfolder24/", "~/Subfolder24/Default.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("Subfolder25 Default", "Subfolder25/", "~/Subfolder25/Default.aspx");
```

---

**The issue with this approach** is that the third parameter of `MapPageRoute` is a path to one specific file, meaning I'd have to write one of these rules for each and every subfolder.  I fear for the developer after me who adds a subfolder and doesn't know to add a record to the RouteConfig file.

---

**The question:** Using Friendly URLs / RouteConfig / RouteMapping, is there a way to conditionally remove one specific page name for *all* folders?

<sup>*(I'd prefer to avoid Web.Config rewrites if possible, as to keep all rewriting consistent.)*</sup>

<sup>* *Project is ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms*</sup>

Comment: Why not just make your own extension method that accepts an array of subfolders and calls `MapPageRoute` to register all of them this way?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Thanks for the suggestion! That's definitely closer to a solution im looking fo,r but I was still hoping for something a bit more generic, so that additional subfolders wouldn't require any route maintenance.